# What is causing the "Error calling CreateEnvelope - TAB_REFERS_TO_MISSING_DOCUMENT" error when creating composite envelope?

Tags: docusignapi

I have the following code that is supposed to send an envelope with multiple templates to sign:

```
public void SendEvelope(List<string> templateIds)
{
    var envelope = new EnvelopeDefinition { EmailSubject = "Please sign this", Status = "created", CompositeTemplates = new List<CompositeTemplate>() };
    var ct = new CompositeTemplate { ServerTemplates = new List<ServerTemplate>(), InlineTemplates = new List<InlineTemplate>() };
    foreach (var templateId in templateIds)
    {
        var template = _templatesApi.Get(AccountId, templateId);
        if (template == null) continue;
        ct.ServerTemplates.Add(new ServerTemplate { TemplateId = templateId, Sequence = "1" });
        var it = new InlineTemplate
        {
            Sequence = "1",
            Recipients = new Recipients { Signers = new List<Signer>() }
        };
        var signer = new Signer
        {
            Name = "John Doe",
            Email = "me@here.com",
            RoleName = "Client",
            RecipientId = "1"
        };
        it.Recipients.Signers.Add(signer);
        ct.InlineTemplates.Add(it);
        envelope.CompositeTemplates.Add(ct);
    }
    _envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(AccountId, envelope);
}
```

The code seems to be working properly until it gets to the CreateEnvelope command at which point it crashes with the following error:

**Error calling CreateEnvelope: {   "errorCode":
 "TAB_REFERS_TO_MISSING_DOCUMENT",   "message": "The DocumentId specified in
 the tab element does not refer to a document in this envelope. Tab refers
 to DocumentId 54017690 which is not present." }**

I am not specifying any tabs or documents in my call and each template I am adding to the envelope exists for sure since they are being fetched one at a time from the API. So what is the problem here? What am I missing?

EDIT:

Here is the full stack trace:

```
DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException: Error calling CreateEnvelope: {
"errorCode": "TAB_REFERS_TO_MISSING_DOCUMENT",
"message": "The DocumentId specified in the tab element does not refer to a document in this envelope. Tab refers to DocumentId 54017690 which is not present."
}
at DocuSign.eSign.Api.EnvelopesApi.CreateEnvelopeWithHttpInfo(String accountId, EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition, CreateEnvelopeOptions options) in y:\Docusign\Github\DevCenter\SDKs\csharp\sdk\src\main\csharp\DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi.cs:line 2606
at DocuSign.eSign.Api.EnvelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(String accountId, EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition, CreateEnvelopeOptions options) in y:\Docusign\Github\DevCenter\SDKs\csharp\sdk\src\main\csharp\DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi.cs:line 2532
at LeadDocket.Core.Services.DocuSignService.SendEvelope(List`1 templateIds, Int32 leadId, Settings settings) in C:\inetpub\Websites\LeadDocket\Source\LeadDocket.Core\Services\DocuSignService.cs:line 64
at LeadDocket.Website.Controllers.LeadsController.PickTemplates(PickTemplatesViewModel model) in C:\inetpub\Websites\LeadDocket\Source\LeadDocket.Website\Controllers\LeadsController.cs:line 638
at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

EDIT 2:

Here is what I get in the log:

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net:7801/restapi/v2/accounts/1661307/envelopes
Content-Length: 2148
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Host: demo.docusign.net
User-Agent: RestSharp/100.0.0.0
X-DocuSign-SDK: C#
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"mmijuskovic@somedomain.com", "Password":"[omitted]", "IntegratorKey":"[omitted]"}
X-Forwarded-For: 157.182.105.1
X-SecurityProtocol-Version: TLSv1
X-SecurityProtocol-CipherSuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-CBC-SHA

{"compositeTemplates":[{"serverTemplates":[{"sequence":"1","templateId":"3639308e-778d-46bf-9f82-04834166a2a6"},{"sequence":"1","templateId":"50c95d3c-0d55-4dca-924c-73dbf1437b27"},{"sequence":"1","templateId":"98960d61-f3e5-4fda-958c-122b972eecdd"}],"inlineTemplates":[{"sequence":"1","recipients":{"signers":[{"name":"Heather M. Batz","email":"me@here.com","recipientId":"1","roleName":"Client"}]}},{"sequence":"1","recipients":{"signers":[{"name":"Heather M. Batz","email":"me@here.com","recipientId":"1","roleName":"Client"}]}},{"sequence":"1","recipients":{"signers":[{"name":"Heather M. Batz","email":"me@here.com","recipientId":"1","roleName":"Client"}]}}]},{"serverTemplates":[{"sequence":"1","templateId":"3639308e-778d-46bf-9f82-04834166a2a6"},{"sequence":"1","templateId":"50c95d3c-0d55-4dca-924c-73dbf1437b27"},{"sequence":"1","templateId":"98960d61-f3e5-4fda-958c-122b972eecdd"}],"inlineTemplates":[{"sequence":"1","recipients":{"signers":[{"name":"Heather M. Batz","email":"me@here.com","recipientId":"1","roleName":"Client"}]}},{"sequence":"1","recipients":{"signers":[{"name":"Heather M. Batz","email":"me@here.com","recipientId":"1","roleName":"Client"}]}},{"sequence":"1","recipients":{"signers":[{"name":"Heather M. Batz","email":"me@here.com","recipientId":"1","roleName":"Client"}]}}]},{"serverTemplates":[{"sequence":"1","templateId":"3639308e-778d-46bf-9f82-04834166a2a6"},{"sequence":"1","templateId":"50c95d3c-0d55-4dca-924c-73dbf1437b27"},{"sequence":"1","templateId":"98960d61-f3e5-4fda-958c-122b972eecdd"}],"inlineTemplates":[{"sequence":"1","recipients":{"signers":[{"name":"Heather M. Batz","email":"me@here.com","recipientId":"1","roleName":"Client"}]}},{"sequence":"1","recipients":{"signers":[{"name":"Heather M. Batz","email":"me@here.com","recipientId":"1","roleName":"Client"}]}},{"sequence":"1","recipients":{"signers":[{"name":"Heather M. Batz","email":"me@here.com","recipientId":"1","roleName":"Client"}]}}]}],"status":"sent","emailSubject":"Local Firm - Please sign this"}
400 BadRequest
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
  "errorCode": "TAB_REFERS_TO_MISSING_DOCUMENT",
  "message": "The DocumentId specified in the tab element does not refer to a document in this envelope. Tab refers to DocumentId 54017690 which is not present."
}
```

Comment: Best way to debug this is to trace the raw request your code is sending out and post that here (you can redact any confidential info).  Please capture your request through a tool like Fiddler or you can enable request logging through your account settings (look under Privacy) and post the JSON that is being created and sent out.  We should be able to diagnose based on that...

Comment: @Ergin Please take a look at the updated question I included the log...

Comment: For starters I don't believe you can have multiple `serverTemplate` sections and `inlineTemplate` sections etc.  You need to combine ALL of your server templates into one larger `serverTemplates` node, and do the same for your `inlineTemplates`.  If that doesn't resolve I think the best thing to try is just send two templates, get that working, then start adding more in.